# Git: merging two diverged, independent repos

Tags: svn, git, git-rebase, git-merge

Repository A: migrated to git from a project's SVN at revision `r`: cloned the whole thing including all of SVN's history, tags, etc. A little development on git afterwards.

Repository B: the same project, but independently migrated from SVN at revision `r+small_number`. Only the latest snapshot was brought into git. Lots of independent development afterwards.

Now I merged A into B. The idea is that SVN will be discarded, development will continue in the `develop` branch of the project's repo on GitHub. I used simple merge to do the job; thankfully there were very few [real conflicts](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/commit/d96f1003e11d2906c4cb798ed6040b5532cd3be0). The development was mostly in different areas, though there was a lot of cleaning up after the merge, unrelated to git.

**But:** now when I do e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~2` on the [merged result](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/tree/develop), which I understand should let me rebase the last two commits, I am greeted with a page of some 300+ commits -- **the complete history of the project since revision 1 in SVN**. I aborted the rebase for fear of messing up even more (obviously I'm a complete Git novice).

Is that outcome expected? Is it desirable? If not, how to fix it?

*Note that all unit tests etc. pass, the files themselves are ok, only I don't understand what happened to git metadata/history.*

EDIT: this is what I ****think**** the repository looks like now:

```
          r         A
... o --- o --- ... o 
                     \ 
               B      \    
    o --- .... o ----  o --- ... o 
   r+small_number      C         HEAD
```

Comment: Is one of the commits you are trying to rebase the merge commit?

Comment: @cebewee: No, not **the** merge commit that joined the two repos. It is a merge commit though, a later one.

Comment: So both parents of the merge commit directly before HEAD have C as ancestor? Can you make the repositories public?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this behaviour occurs because you are trying to rebase over a merge commit.

For the following answer, I'm assuming that your history looks like this, i.e. repositories A and B are completely independent:

```
          r         A
... o --- o --- ... o

o ... o
r'    B
```

You need to ask yourself what are you trying to achieve? So you want to have a new branch C containing both the changes in A and B. What are the priorities here? Do you want to achieve a proper history; correcting the fact that `r'` lost its SVN history? Or is it important to keep the git history of A and B unchanged?

My answer is going to assume you want to achieve the former. As both A and B descendet from very similar versions of the SVN repository, it might be a good idea to give them a common git base *before* merging the common history. So, ideally before merging you would have the situation:

```
          r          A
... o --- o --- .... o
           \
            \
             o --- .... o
       r+small_number   B
```

At the moment, I'm not sure which is the best way to achieve this, but you could try doing `git rebase -p --onto r --root B`.

Then you could just `git merge` A and B and end up with the history

```
          r          A     C
... o --- o --- .... o --- o
           \              /
            \            /
             o --- .... o
       r+small_number   B
```

where C contains all your changes. I would probably leave it at that; without any further rebasing.

Comment: That second graph is lovely, that's exactly what I should have done. Too bad. History before `r` I don't care about, in fact any history up to now can be discarded if necessary. I'd like to accept your answer @cebewee, but please shed some light on why the rebase acts like it does now? Will it act like this forever unless I run the `rebase -p --onto` you recommend,  or will things smooth out as I progress from the merge point? And is it just rebase or are merges affected as well? EDIT: I'm already more than 2 commits away from the merge point C...

Comment: In principle, git does not have problems with multiple roots in a repository (such things are even used in the official git repository), so git is expected to handle this situation fine. Also, merges will not be affected. I tried to reproduce your situation but failed

Comment: @Radim: When I do a `rebase` over a merge commit; I get all commits up to the merge base of the (two) parents of the merge -- so are you really sure, these commits have an common ancestor.

Comment: @Radim:What does `git merge-base <commit>^1 <commit^2>` output, were <commit> is the merge commit you are rebasing over?

Comment: The weirdness happens when rebasing over an innocent looking [merge 3 commits back](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/commit/48be6e1948a6d79ee74f238ae99c1c013b9a46e5). `git merge-base 48be6e1948a^1 48be6e1948a^2` outputs `c0e2b73ecb78e41fe805d2803eb3df9451d642f6`.
I tested what happens when I add more commits (move away from the merge point `C` further); rebases look ok then. 

So I guess your "rebase over  merge" is really the culprit somehow; I am accepting your answer. I will leave the repo with two roots, as you say it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ok, now it becomes more clear. The problematic commit is the merge c0e2b73ec. The merge base computed for its parents is 74c3aa1d, which does *not* contain your root commit 7dfc5ce044. The reason is that the first parent of the merge (5410fc2f) is based on a part of your repository *before* the merge which joined A and B. If you want to visualize this, I found the graphs drawn by qgit more readable then those by gitk for this task. HTH.